# Hibernate allows query only once in my DAO class

Tags: hibernate, session

I attempted to write a DAO class to validate a user's login on a web page, however, the Hibernate query seems working only once. When the user tries to log in second time, Hibernate throws lots of errors:

```
public boolean isUserAndPasswordValid(String username, String password)
    {
        User user = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from User where username = :username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);

    user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
//        List<?> list = query.list();
        tx.commit();

//        if (list.size() == 0)
//            return false;

//        user = (User) list.get(0);

    HibernateUtil.closeSessionFactory();

    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.getPassword().equals(User.md5Spring(password)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As I am novice to hibernate query language, I am not sure I am doing the query correctly. Could some of you guys point to me where might be wrong? Also, regarding the Session returned from SessionFactory, why can't I just do the following? as it seems very intuitive to me (search the entity table "User" for the "username"?)

```
user = (User) session.get(User.class, username);
```

Below is the error message when attemping second login: (btw, I am using Ninja framework along with Hibernate)

```
17:38:11.803 [qtp362239120-16] ERROR ninja.NinjaImpl - Emitting bad request 400. Something really wrong when calling route: /admin/loginPost (class: class controllers.AdministrationController method: public ninja.Result controllers.AdministrationController.loginPost(ninja.Context,models.User))
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1589) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext.buildOrObtainSession(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext.currentSession(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at dao.UserDao.isUserAndPasswordValid(UserDao.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.AdministrationController.loginPost(AdministrationController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at ninja.params.ControllerMethodInvoker.invoke(ControllerMethodInvoker.java:55) ~[ninja-core-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at ninja.FilterChainEnd.next(FilterChainEnd.java:48) ~[ninja-core-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at ninja.NinjaImpl.invoke(NinjaImpl.java:112) ~[ninja-core-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at ninja.servlet.NinjaServletDispatcher.service(NinjaServletDispatcher.java:83) [ninja-servlet-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1615) [jetty-servlet-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550) [jetty-servlet-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112) [jetty-server-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479) [jetty-servlet-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046) [jetty-server-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459) [jetty-server-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281) [jetty-server-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232) [jetty-server-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505) [jetty-io-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607) [jetty-util-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536) [jetty-util-9.1.2.v20140210.jar:9.1.2.v20140210]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building HibernateSessionFactory is expensive. It should be done only once at the start of your application. And close as part of your server or application shutdown.

Session objects should be created and closed for each request. And also for read only queries do not need to be part of the transaction. So you can remove transaction begin and commit lines and closeSessionFactory lines and try.

So if you comment HibernateUtil.closeSessionFactory() line, it will work fine.